# How to print certain things when a user types a specific word? (Python 3.11.1)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Newbie student coder, and perhaps because it's late and I'm a lil stupid, but I can't seem to figure out how to make my convertor program work.

Basically, I'm trying to write this weight convertor using planets and factor numbers provided by my teacher. The user is to input a weight and then type in a planet name, thus converting the weight into what it would be on that planet.

I'm trying to use loops, and maybe that's not the right approach, but idk. This is my current code:

```
planets = ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Moon', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune', 'Pluto']
factors = ['0.4155', '0.8975', '1.000', '0.166', '0.3507', '2.5374', '1.0677', '0.8947', '1.1794', '0.0899']
planets_factors = dict(zip(planets, factors))


class WeightConvertor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_weight = user_weight
        self.planet = planet

    def __str__(self):
        return f"user_weight = {self.user_weight} planet = {self.planet}"

    def convertor():
        print("This choice allows you to see your weight on another planet.")
        print()
        print(planets)
        user_choice = input("Please choose a planet from the list above: ").upper()
        user_weight = float(input("Please enter your weight here: "))
        print()
        print()
        planet_choice = []
        for user_choice in planets:
            if user_choice == "Mercury":
                print("You chose Mercury.")
                converted_mercury = user_weight * 0.4155
                print()
                print("Your weight on", user_choice, "is", converted_mercury)
                print()
            elif user_choice == "Venus":
                print("You chose Venus.")
                converted_venus = user_weight * 0.8975
                print()
                print("Your weight on", user_choice, "is", converted_venus)
                print()
            elif user_choice == "Earth":
                print("You chose Earth.")
                converted_earth = user_weight * 1.000
                print()
                print("Your weight on", user_choice, "is", converted_earth)
                print()
            elif user_choice == "Moon":
                print("You chose Moon.")
                converted_moon = user_weight * 0.166
                print()
                print("Your weight on", user_choice, "is", converted_moon)
                print()
            elif user_choice == "Mars":
                print("You chose Mars.")
                converted_mars = user_weight * 0.3507
                print()
                print("Your weight on", user_choice, "is", converted_mars)
                print()
            elif user_choice == "Jupiter":
                print("You chose Jupiter.")
                converted_jupiter = user_weight * 2.5374
                print()
                print("Your weight on", user_choice, "is", converted_jupiter)
                print()
            elif user_choice == "Saturn":
                print("You chose Saturn.")
                converted_saturn = user_weight * 1.0677
                print()
                print("Your weight on", user_choice, "is", converted_saturn)
                print()
            elif user_choice == "Uranus":
                print("You chose Uranus.")
                converted_uranus = user_weight * 0.8947
                print()
                print("Your weight on", user_choice, "is", converted_uranus)
                print()
            elif user_choice == "Neptune":
                print("You chose Neptune.")
                converted_neptune = user_weight * 1.1794
                print()
                print("Your weight on", user_choice, "is", converted_neptune)
                print()
            elif user_choice == "Pluto":
                print("You chose Pluto.")
                converted_pluto = user_weight * 0.0899
                print()
                print("Your weight on", user_choice, "is", converted_pluto)
                print()
        else:
            print("Invalid Option")
            print("Please Try Again")
            print()
            user_choice = input("Please choose a planet from the list: ")

WeightConvertor.convertor()
```

So far, doing "while user_choice != planets", "for user_choice in planets", "if user_choice in planets" doesn't work.
The while loop and if user_choice gets me the else portion of "Invalid Option, Please Try again".

The for loop just prints all of the planet weight conversions out when I just want the user inputted one.
For ranges, I've attempted it, and maybe I'm doing something wrong but I also get the "Invalid Option, Please Try Again" error message I wrote at the bottom.
I've also tried just leaving it as if, elif, elif, elif, etc. etc. and that didn't work either.

I don't really get what else to do. I don't remember my teacher showing us anything else and I'm supposed to use only techniques and libraries used in class. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for the help everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `upper()`

you are doing:

```
user_choice = input("Please choose a planet from the list above: ").upper()
```

it will convert all the `user_choice` to upper case.

Remove `upper()` or change the names to upper case in if/elif conditions like `MERCURY`, `VENUS`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So:

1.Instruction

```
for user_choice in planets:
```

takes takes one of each elements from list of planets. "user choice" used here has nothing to do with previously created variable.

for example, for this code:

```
i = 100
for i in [1,2,3]:
    print(i)
```

printed values will be olny 1, 2 and 3.

it's because loop declares variable "i" again, losing it's previous value.

2. the whole idea of using dictionaries is you can get second value via key (first value). you don't have to use any ifs.

for example:

```
planets = ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth']
factors = ['0.4155', '0.8975', '1.000']
planets_factors = dict(zip(planets, factors))

print(planets_factors['Venus'])
```

will print out factor used for Venus (0.8975).

in your project, it should be sth like this:

```
user_choice = input("Please choose a planet from the list above: ")
user_weight = float(input("Please enter your weight here: "))
if user_choice in planets:
    print('You chose', user_choice)
    converted_value = user_weight * planet_factors[user_choice] 
    #dictionary allows you to get value via key
print("Your weight on", user_choice, "is", converted_value)
else:
print("Invalid Option")
print("Please Try Again")
print()
convertor()
```

3. Remember, that inputed string and this used in dictionary have to be identical. if you want to give user premission to write 'mercury' insted of 'Mercury', you should give ".upper()" next to every "user_choice" and "planet_factors[user_choice]".

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary has keys in mixed case. In order to match those the input has to be the same. You can normalise the input with str.title()

Also, as you have a dictionary that maps the planets to their conversion factors you don't need the complex if/else structure that you're currently using.

Try this:

```
class WeightConvertor:
    PLANET_MAP = {
        'Mercury': 0.4155,
        'Venus': 0.8975,
        'Earth': 1.000,
        'Moon': 0.166,
        'Mars': 0.3507,
        'Jupiter': 2.5374,
        'Saturn': 1.0677,
        'Uranus': 0.8947,
        'Neptune': 1.1794,
        'Pluto': 0.0899
    }
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    @staticmethod
    def convertor():
        print('The planets are:-', *WeightConvertor.PLANET_MAP)
        while (selection := input('Please choose a planet (or return to end): ')):
            if (factor := WeightConvertor.PLANET_MAP.get(selection.title())):
                weight = input('What is your weight? ')
                try:
                    cv = float(weight) * factor
                    print(f'Your weight on {selection} is {cv:.2f}')
                except ValueError as e:
                    print(e)
            else:
                print(f'{selection} is not a planet that I know of. Please try again')

WeightConvertor.convertor()
```